# Faster way for array comparison matlab: How?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to compare two large arrays to each other and do some extra operations. So far it works but it is very slow. Coming from a little C++ background, I can use pointers to their location instead of taking the value of each. I have found how to do so in matlab using shrlib but I am not sure if it works for doubles.

What I have available:

Two textfiles each in the following format: name in col 1, value1 in col2 and value2 in col 3

```
  filename       value1       value2
---------------------------------------
  foo0001         100          200
  foo0001         140          200
  foo0001         135          155
  foo0002         124          145
  foo0002         135          155
  foo0003         1419         1943
     .             .            .
     .             .            . 
  and so on...
```

- my first goal is to compare the values of value1 and value2 from the first file to those of the second file.
- second I want to also be tolerant to errors with respect to elements from value1 and value2
- third I want the file comparison to run fast ( my current method is very slow)

So here is what I have done so far:

```
      file1 = readtable('file1.txt',...
      'Delimiter',' ','ReadVariableNames',false);
      fclose(fileID);         %% Read the files in the form of table


      file2 = readtable('file2.txt',...
      'Delimiter',' ','ReadVariableNames',false);
      fclose(fileID);         %% Read the files in the form of table

      n = 1000;
      detectedCorn = zeros(n,2);   %initialize large nx2 vectors to save value1 and value2
      referenceCorn = zeros(n,2);
      null = ['foo000',int2str(ip)]; % initialize filename as "dynamic" string
      for ip = 1:100
      iv = 1;   % initialize index variables to use later on
      iv2 = 1;  %

      for ii = 1:numel(file1.Var1) %% all Var1 -> name in first col in file1 table


   if strcmp(file1.Var1(ii), null) == 1;
       var = [file1.Var2(ii),file1.Var3(ii)];
      detectedCorn(iv,:) = var;
      var = zeros(1,2);
       iv = iv + 1;
   end

    %REPEAT SAME STEP AS ABOVE FOR file2( I will skip that so the code doesnt get too crowded)
for kk = 1:1000
for rr = 1:1000
    var3 = [0,0];

if all(ismember(detectedCorn(kk,:),var3)) == 0  && all(ismember(referenceCorn(kk,:),var3)) == 0   %% do not count the empty spaces in the array
if all(ismember(detectedCorn(kk,:),referenceCorn(rr,:))) == 1  %% iterate through the two vectors and compare 

    % do something

else
   % do something else

end


end

end

end

end
```

After the if statement: `if all(ismember(detectedCorn(kk,:),referenceCorn(rr,:))) == 1` I would like to add some other if statements to make it more tolerant for values. ex:

if the value inside the vector is 145+/-2 ---> do something.

sorry for the bad code formatting,

```
      ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Clarification: 

  For example I have these files:
  file 1: Reference
  imagename.png       value1    value2
  000000004.png       100        200
  000000004.png       120        130
  000000004.png       150        1500
  000000005.png       1214       501
 file 2: Detected
 imagename.png        value1    value2
  000000004.png       100       200
  000000004.png       204       300
  000000004.png       300       400
  000000004.png       129       140
  000000004.png       152       1499        
  000000005.png       1200      500
```

What I mean by compare, I want to do the following: 
for example the first row in the Detected file (file2) I have row1. First thing I have to make sure that the filenames in the two files are the same. If that so then I can compare the data in x and y. if difference of value1 from Detected file (in this example 100) and the value1 from Reference file is equal to 0,1,2,-1,-2 then, check if difference of value2 of the same row in both files equal to 0,1,2,-1,-2, increment the variable TP (Positive match) with 1. And so on for all files... By that logic the for the above data TP = 2, FP = data found in Detected but not in reference and FN is data found in reference but not in detected.

Notice that file detected has way more entries than the first file and does not necessarily have the same filenames

Comment: Your code is kind of hard to read (probably because it's not very MATLABy). Can you clarify what sort of comparison you want to do? e.g. you seem to have multiple entries in the file for some of your filenames.  Are you looking to return the filenames where all the values in both files match (or nearly match)? Can we presume that if there are three entries for foo0001 in the first file there are three entries for foo0001 in the second? (but maybe different numbers for foo0002, it seems).

Comment: Yeah I tried to program it with C++ logic. I have some reference data in one text file and I have detected data in the other text file. The data in the detected file is larger than the one in the reference data. So to answer your question if  foo0001 in the first file has 3 foo0001 in the second file may have 100. and foo0002 in the first file may have 5 entries and in the other file may have way more. (same for foo000x). I am looking to only COUNT how many files are close or the same. So inside the second for loop where `%do something` is there would be something like `N = N + 1`

Comment: So if there's three foo0001 entries in the first file, if any of those three lines match any foo0001 line in the second file, that's a hit?

Comment: yeah exactly (match or is close by that number with a tolerance of +/- 2 either in x, or y or in both)

Comment: I thought of copying the referencecorn array and adding the tolerances. (one array with + 1 ,  one with - 1, one with + 2 and one with -2) but there has to be a better way than doing that (maybe a built in function ? )

Comment: I know this isn't particularly concrete help, but if you're planning on using Matlab, I would seriously recommend that you work through some tutorials first and familiarize yourself not just with the language, but also with its style. Programming C++-style in Matlab is kind of pointless. – Regarding the question itself, its not clear to me what exactly you are trying to achieve. Best would be to give small toy example input files along with the desired output. What do you mean by "compare"? Compute the difference? What kind of errors are you talking about. Etc. etc.

Comment: @A.Donda Thank you for your time. Yes I totally agree with the C++ style, the only problem is I am under time pressure so I can not dedicate my time for going through the tutorials. I am figuring out how matlab works bit by bit, I am trying to use logical arrays to improve the performance. However it doesn't seem as intuitive as I thought and is taking a bit more time. by compare I mean compute the difference, if it is 0,+1,+2,-1,-2 then it is a match. I will update my question shortly so you would get an idea what I am trying to achieve.